# How to join/merge two json objects using sailsjs-nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, sails.js

Hello I am new to Sailsjs-Nodejs. In my controller I have two JSON Objects I need to merge/join so I can make third to send response

res.send(obj1) output

```
[
  {
    total_fare: "376",
    arrival_to: "ABV"
  },
  {
    total_fare: "312",
    arrival_to: "ACC"
  },
  {
    total_fare: "432",
    arrival_to: "BFN"
  }
]
```

res.send(obj2) output

```
[
  {
    url: "nigeria.php",
    country: "Nigeria",
    city_code: "ABV"
  },
  {
    url: "ghana.php",
    country: "Ghana",
    city_code: "ACC"
  },
  {
    url: "south-africa.php",
    country: "South Africa",
    city_code: "BFN"
  }
]
```

Here is my expected result 
res.send(obj3) should output

```
[
  {
    url: "nigeria.php",
    country: "Nigeria",
    city_code: "ABV",
    total_fare: "376",
    arrival_to: "ABV"
  },
  {
    url: "ghana.php",
    country: "Ghana",
    city_code: "ACC",
    total_fare: "312",
    arrival_to: "ACC"
  },
  {
    url: "south-africa.php",
    country: "South Africa",
    city_code: "BFN",
    total_fare: "432",
    arrival_to: "BFN"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do as follows without modifying the source arrays;

```js
var arr = [{total_fare: "376",arrival_to: "ABV"},
           {total_fare: "312",arrival_to: "ACC"},
           {total_fare: "432",arrival_to: "BFN"}],
    brr = [{url: "nigeria.php",country: "Nigeria",city_code: "ABV"},
           {url: "ghana.php",country: "Ghana",city_code: "ACC"},
           {url: "south-africa.php",country: "South Africa",city_code: "BFN"}],
 merged = arr.map((o,i) => Object.assign({},o,brr[i]));
 console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.

Using `lodash` package I'm using `_.map()` to walk through total fares,
and using `_.find()` I'm finding first ocurrence by `arrival_to == city_code` and do `_.extend()` joining objects.

This example is helpful when Your array of objects are **not sequential** and also if there will be **more total fares than elements in country list**.

I've specially added `{total_fare: "111",arrival_to: "ACC"}` to show You and example when there is 2 or more objects with same `arrival_to` field.

```js
// const _ = require('lodash'); //uncomment on serverside usage

let totalFares = [{total_fare: "376",arrival_to: "ABV"},
           {total_fare: "312",arrival_to: "ACC"},
           {total_fare: "432",arrival_to: "BFN"},
           {total_fare: "111",arrival_to: "ACC"}];

let countries = 
           [{url: "nigeria.php",country: "Nigeria",city_code: "ABV"},
           {url: "ghana.php",country: "Ghana",city_code: "ACC"},
           {url: "south-africa.php",country: "South Africa",city_code: "BFN"}];

totalFares = _.map(totalFares, (totalFare) => {
    _.extend(totalFare, _.find(countries, 
                              (country) => 
                               country.city_code == totalFare.arrival_to));

    return totalFare;
});

console.log(totalFares);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.14.1/dist/lodash.js"></script>
```